# Could I use JSON for communication between processes implemented in different programming languages?

Tags: java, c++, xml, json, language-agnostic

I know that `XML` can be used so that programs in different programming languages could communicate.
E.g. a `Java` server with `C` and `Python` clients.
Could `JSON` be used as an alternative?  I mean also if it can *should* I go for it? Especially in a case where the clients are not controlled by me.
Would you feel that implementing such a client `XML` would be prefered?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Just use appropriate Json libraries on both ends (e.g. [JsonCPP](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) on the C++ side, or [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) in C). And learn more about [json-rpc](http://json-rpc.org/).

The big advantage of JSON over XML is that it is simpler (to understand, to implement, to use) and probably less verbose (so shorter messages).

You could also consider [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) which seems less used, but is more "powerful".

Don't forget to document quite well your JSON protocol (i.e. messages).

Comment: May be my OP was not clear. If I can, *should* I do it? I mean is it a viable/good alternative especially if the clients are not controlled by me?

Comment: +1 for the last comment.I in generally have always been *not* a big fun of XML. I think it is misused in the sense that it is used even when hierarchy in data is not present

Comment: Or [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) since it's supported by almost any language, results in smaller serialized data and you don't even have to write a single line of code to parse / serialize it. There are RPC implementations on top of it as well.

Comment: But why `RPC`? Isn't using a `Remote Procedure Call` style "archaic"? Why not just generic messages?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should JSON.

There are many libraries for JSON in nearly all well known languages. And a JSON file with the same content as a XML file is about 75% smaller. So you should use it :D

Answer (score 1):

Per your question of should you do it, I think it's an appropriate use.  In the end you simply need something that both ends of the conversation can handle.  You could use XML or some other alternative, but I don't think it's any better/worse from a 'should you' perspective.

Sorry for the separate answer.  Lacking the rep to comment...

Answer (score 0):

**You can, but you should not.** Don't get me wrong, JSON is OK as data-interchange languages go, but the XML serialization packages for just about any language are much more mature than most JSON packages.  Yes, XML is larger than JSON, and there's good reason - it carries a lot more descriptive information than JSON does.  And the more diverse your "endpoints" are, the more that information can help in maintaining robust communication.

Comment: I understand your point.So as a follow up question, if I don't need so much descriptive information do you still stick by your suggestion?